# Puppeteer eval issues

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am having issues trying to get this to work. 
I am needing to select the calendar heading "May 2020", but am not having any luck, could I get someone to look at what I am doing wrong?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('https://www.stayz.com.au/holiday-rental/p9177051?noDates=true',{waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

   const headingTxt = await page.evaluate(() => 
      document.querySelector('#rates-availability > div > div > section > div > div.inline-calendar > div > div.cal-controls__calendar-parent--middle-multi > div > div:nth-child(2) > h4 > span').innerText);

  console.log('');
  console.log('========[ output ]======== ', headingTxt);
  console.log('');

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: well there's no way to know what the HTML layout of the page looks like. If you simply return `=> document.querySelector('#rates-availability').innerText`, does it give some result? Also in some cases, you may need to wait for navigation before doing page.evaluate

Comment: it works in the browser console but not with puppeteer. document.querySelector('#rates-availability') in the console will return a result but not in puppeteer

Comment: For me, `document.querySelector('#rates-availability > div > div > section > div > div.inline-calendar > div > div.cal-controls__calendar-parent--middle-multi > div > div:nth-child(2) > h4 > span')` returns `null` in console. Could it be that you test it in console when signed in, while in puppeteer session you signed out?

Comment: Oh, it seems this element is added dynamically when you scroll the page. Try to scroll the page in puppeteer till it appears.

Comment: How would you add a scroll into this as i am new to this puppeteer

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

This selector needs scrolling and wide viewport to appear:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized'] }); //
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 850 });
  await page.goto('https://www.stayz.com.au/holiday-rental/p9177051?noDates=true', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

  const selector = '#rates-availability > div > div > section > div > div.inline-calendar > div > div.cal-controls__calendar-parent--middle-multi > div > div:nth-child(2) > h4 > span';

  while ((await page.$(selector)) === null) {
    await page.evaluate(() => { window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight); });
    await page.waitFor(1000);
  }

  const headingTxt = await page.evaluate(
    selector => document.querySelector(selector).innerText,
    selector
  );

  console.log('');
  console.log('========[ output ]======== ', headingTxt);
  console.log('');

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```